# make wrapped text one line using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with following records:

```
1  Error    19-03-23   02:02:26     LPU 6 : RX_PWR_L_ALARM of SFPF ALARM of                        
                                    PIC1 is abnormal[OID:1.3.6.1.4.1.201
                                    1.5.25.129.2.1.9,BasCode:67697]
2  Error    19-03-20   07:50:40     The air filter : Maybe it is not clean
                                    ed as scheduled. Please clean it and            
                                    run the reset dustproof run-time comman
                                    d[OID:1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.25.129.2.1.9,
                                    BasCode:67995]
```

I want to output:

```
1 Error 19-03-23 02:02:26 LPU 6 : RX_PWR_L_ALARM of SFPF ALARM of PIC1 is abnormal[OID:1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.25.129.2.1.9,BasCode:67697]

2 Error 19-03-20 07:50:40 The air filter : Maybe it is not cleaned as scheduled. Please clean it and run the reset dustproof run-time command[OID:1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.25.129.2.1.9,BasCode:67995]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

GNU `sed`:

```
 sed -En '/^[[:digit:]]+[[:blank:]]+/{:l1;N;/]$/!{b l1};s/\n +//g;s/ +/ /g;s/ /\t/g;s/\t/ /5gp}' file
```

*Output*

```
1   Error   19-03-23    02:02:26    LPU 6 : RX_PWR_L_ALARM of SFPF ALARM of PIC1 is abnormal[OID:1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.25.129.2.1.9,BasCode:67697]
2   Error   19-03-20    07:50:40    The air filter : Maybe it is not cleaned as scheduled. Please clean it and run the reset dustproof run-time command[OID:1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.25.129.2.1.9,BasCode:67995]
```

Comment: @oguz-ismail : Thank you for the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55899264/3). In fact this is not possible with any other `sed` version it uses `GNU` extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  if($0 ~ / +$/){
    sub(/ +$/," ")
  }
}
FNR==1{
  printf("%s",$0)
  next
}
{
  if($0 ~ /^ +/){
    check=1
    sub(/^ +/,"")
  }
  printf("%s%s",check==1?"":ORS,$0)
  check=""
}'  Input_file
```

following is the output I am getting.

```
1  Error    19-03-23   02:02:26     LPU 6 : RX_PWR_L_ALARM of SFPF ALARM of PIC1 is abnormal[OID:1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.25.129.2.1.9,BasCode:67697]
2  Error    19-03-20   07:50:40     The air filter : Maybe it is not cleaned as scheduled. Please clean it and run the reset dustproof run-time command[OID:1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.5.25.129.2.1.9,BasCode:67995]
```

Comment: Won't print a line feed (`\n`) at the end of file

Comment: good. but the first issue I mentinoed is still there. Is something wrong with your terminal?

Comment: @oguzismail, should be good now, not sure about new line, it shows ok to me, will check more on it and update.

Comment: if i use this code, i cant insert into mysql.